# this.store.metadataFor doesn't work in ember 1.13

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Recently I was using 1.9 version of ember and beta16 of ember data and `_this.store.metadataFor('user')` worked perfectly for response like this

```
meta: {
  isLogin: true
  privateKey: null
  roomCode: "dea2ac4c0407886bac7d8fd092379a6e"
}
user:{
  id:1,
  login:'Alex'
}
```

---

But after upgrading to ember 1.13.2 and ember-data 1.13.2 `_this.store.metadataFor('user')`  returns an empty object. 
Maybe something has changed in ember, but I didn't found any solutions to solve it. Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Your response looks odd-  Normally, at the top level there would be a `meta` and a `users` array.  The individual `user` object would be in the `users` array...

Comment: users array are for host.com/users
user object is for host.com/users/:id . And it worked perfectly in previous version. I suggest there is some kind of framework error in 1.13

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will bump into the same issue https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3398/files . There is really bug in 1.13 ember data. I've just simply changed my ember-data.js like in the pr. Or you can use canary version.